# SQL One to One relation (Additional entity attributes in the second table) advantages

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Quite a few times I saw models with 1 to (1 or 0) relations. E.G.:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(login VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, password VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE people(login VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR, inn VARCHAR, age INTEGER...);
```

sometimes `people` has foreign key set on login column too, sometimes it doesnt.

So my question is what are the advantages and disadvantages of such a model and are the tables normalised here? (as far as I know they are, but they still look strange that way)

PS. I have a homework assignment on databases and I need to design a complex enough model. This is a technique that some students use in order to make more tables.

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about the situation where every account has 1 or 0 people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One practical reason for doing a one-to-one relationship is as a workaround to the row size limits of a MySQL storage engine, without implementing LOB type storage for some columns (moving them to off row storage).

InnoDB has a practical limit of just over 8000 bytes for a maximum row size. Just a couple of VARCHAR(4000) columns will throw you over that limit.

Another reason is that they are actually separate entities. Here, I'm using the term "entity" as it's commonly used in Entity Relationship Modeling techniques,  (roughly) defined as as a "person, place, thing, concept or event that can be uniquely identified that we need to store information about".  If the are truly two separate entities, we often want to have them implemented as separate tables. The "1-to-1"-ness of the relationship is not the usual relationship we find (requirements discovery-wise) between two entities. We more frequently find a 1-to-many or many-to-many relationship between entities.

Another reason to implement a 1-to-1 (or 1-to-0or1) is that the contents of each table is being "stewarded" by a different process. For example, one process responsible for adding/updating rows in the "person" table, perhaps there's an overnight job that loads that table from an external source. And there's another process responsible for adding/updating the `accounts` table, maybe that's an online web form application. We sometimes find it preferable that each table is "stewarded" by a single process.

Those are the three big reasons I have. Otherwise, I'd just go with just one table for an entity.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Spencer's reasons, here are a few more:

Security:  It is easier to specify security on a table than on a column.  By putting the passwords in a separate table -- even if encrypted -- access to them is easier to control.

Performance:  This is called "vertical partitioning".  Often, one set of columns might occupy 5% of the space in records, but satisfy 90% of queries.  The overhead of reading the additional columns can be substantial.

Arcane Requirements:  If there is a need to do something like wipe out all the passwords, this can be accomplished with `truncate table` rather than `update . . .`.  One big advantage (in addition to performance) is that the individual passwords do not end up in logs.

Triggers:  If some of the columns have `update` triggers, it might be desirable to isolate them in a separate table, to reduce the frequency of trigger invocation.

As for whether this violates normalization principles.  It might or might not.  That depends on whether the separate instances "seem" like separate entities.

Also, I would not have the `login` as the common key.  I would define the tables more like:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    AccountId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    login VARCHAR unique
    password VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE people (
    PersonId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    AccountId int references account(AccountId)
    name VARCHAR,
    . . .
);
```

(This is schematic.  MySQL ignores inline reference declarations, so you would want an explicit `foreign key` constraint.)